# Elasticsearch node_master change to offline when start node_data

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-ec2

My server EC2 have two node, when i start `node_data` by command `/home/esdata/bin/elasticsearch`,
`node_master` is running  change to offline

Logs in `node_data`, have message error:

```
[2020-12-15T18:08:57,391][WARN ][o.e.c.c.ClusterFormationFailureHelper] [node_data_1] master not discovered yet: have discovered [{node_data_1}{elNK7JY9S4-E51sUY5zitw}{cDTkyu3bTmypDseY7IFrxw}{localhost}{127.0.0.1:8300}{drt}{xpack.installed=true, transform.node=true}]; discovery will continue using [127.0.0.1:9300] from hosts providers and [] from last-known cluster state; node term 0, last-accepted version 0 in term 0
[2020-12-15T18:09:07,392][WARN ][o.e.c.c.ClusterFormationFailureHelper] [node_data_1] master not discovered yet: have discovered [{node_data_1}{elNK7JY9S4-E51sUY5zitw}{cDTkyu3bTmypDseY7IFrxw}{localhost}{127.0.0.1:8300}{drt}{xpack.installed=true, transform.node=true}]; discovery will continue using [127.0.0.1:9300] from hosts providers and [] from last-known cluster state; node term 0, last-accepted version 0 in term 0
```

I try curl it, and result bellow:

```
root@ip-xxx:~# curl -XGET http://localhost:9201
{
  "name" : "node_data_1",
  "cluster_name" : "eslasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "_na_",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.9.1",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "083627f112ba94dffc1232e8b42b73492789ef91",
    "build_date" : "2020-09-01T21:22:21.964974Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.6.2",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
root@ip-xxx:~# curl -XGET http://localhost:9200
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused
```

config for `node_master` in `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml`

```yaml
cluster.name: elasticsearch

node.name: node_master
node.master: true
node.data: true
node.ingest: false
node.ml: false

transport.host: localhost
transport.tcp.port: 9300

path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch

network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9200

discovery.seed_hosts: ["127.0.0.1:9300", "127.0.0.1:8300"]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node_master"]
```

and config for `node_data` in `/home/esdata/config.yml`

```yaml
cluster.name: elasticsearch

node.name: node_data_1
node.master: false
node.data: true
node.ingest: false
node.ml: false

transport.host: localhost
transport.tcp.port: 8300

network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9201

discovery.seed_hosts: ["127.0.0.1:9300", "127.0.0.1:8300"]
```

Can someone help me fix it? Do I've to run two ES instance? How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you install elasticsearch? What is the `path.data` and `path.logs` for your second node? You need an active master running for your cluster to work, so your `node_data_1` won't work alone. Also, if you are running two or more nodes on the same machine, they need to have different a `path.data` configuration. Make sure that your `node_data_1` is not writing in the `path.data` of your `node_master`.

Comment: With the master node, I run it as a service. As for node data, I use elasticsearch locally on the same version as the master node.
When I run it, I see at node data that a new folder is generated: `data`.
With the same pattern and config above, I run it locally with no problem. I think the problem here is related to the network part of AWS that I don't know yet.

Comment: First use different `path.data` for your nodes since they are in the same machine, then try to start your master node, if it starts ok, start your data node and see if it joins the cluster. If it does not join the cluster check the log for both nodes. Also, how many memory are you using for the HEAP on each node and how many memory does your ec2 instance have? What do you have in the logs of both of your instance? Update your question with the errors or warnings.

Comment: I tried to set `path.data` and `path.logs` as you said, but it didn't work either.

I only see the log in node data, because node master has been stopped.
`master not discovered yet: have discovered [{node_data_1} {wh55HQXGSw23_zVbuR-Uxg} {zv5vmkq7SjeXE_aD9GykeQ} {localhost} {127.0.0t }:8300} {drpacked} { .node = true}]; discovery will continue using [127.0.0.1:9300] from hosts providers and [] from last-known cluster state; node term 0, last-accepted version 0 in term 0`

Comment: As for the HEAP limitation, I don't know how to configure my cluster yet.
Here are my EC2 specs:

`/_cat/nodes?h=heap.max => 2gb`

`df -h => total 56G 9.7G 46G 18%`

`Mem: (total) 3933 (used) 3254 (free) 232`

Comment: It seems that you are missing the `cluster.initial_master_nodes` config in your `node_data_1` configuration, it should be there and pointing to `node_master`. Also, I would say that 4GB is too small to run 2 nodes, any reason to run 2 nodes? Have you checked on the setup part of the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup.html)?

Comment: thanks you, i will try split node in each EC2